# MySQL server wont start

Tags: macos, mysql

For some reason, MySQL won't start anymore. Suddenly happened out of the blue.

This is what is written in

> /var/log/system.log

right after I try to open MySQL.

```
Feb  8 16:07:31 mys-MacBook-Air.local System Preferences[2795]: about to perform command
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got user: mybak
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got ruser: (null)
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got service: authorization
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in od_principal_for_user(): No authentication authority returned
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in od_principal_for_user(): failed: 7
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Failed to determine Kerberos principal name.
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Done cleanup3
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Kerberos 5 refuses you
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): pam_sm_authenticate: ntlm
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_acct_mgmt(): OpenDirectory - Membership cache TTL set to 1800.
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in od_record_check_pwpolicy(): retval: 0
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in od_record_attribute_create_cfstring(): returned 2 attributes for dsAttrTypeStandard:AuthenticationAuthority
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Establishing credentials
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Got user: mybak
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Context initialised
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Got euid, egid: 0 0
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Done getpwnam()
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Done setegid() & seteuid()
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_setcred(): pam_sm_setcred: krb5 user mybak doesn't have a principal
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Done cleanup3
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Done seteuid() & setegid()
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Done cleanup4
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_setcred(): pam_sm_setcred: ntlm
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local authorizationhost[4202]: in pam_sm_setcred(): pam_sm_setcred: no domain found skipping
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: UID 501 authenticated as user mybak (UID 501) for right 'com.mysql.administrator.server'
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Succeeded authorizing right 'com.mysql.administrator.server' by client '/Users/mybak/Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL.pre\
fPane/Contents/Resources/mahelper' [4200] for authorization created by '/Applications/System Preferences.app' [2795] (100003,0)
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local coreservicesd[26]: Application App:"System Preferences" [ 0x0/0xc40c4]  @ 0x0x7fe49cb90aa0 tried to be brought forward, but isn't in fPermittedFrontASN\
s ( ( ASN:0x0-0xe40e4:) ), so denying.
Feb  8 16:07:36 mys-MacBook-Air.local WindowServer[176]: [cps/setfront] Failed setting the front application to System Preferences, psn 0x0-0xc40c4, securitySessionID=0x186a4, err=-13066
Feb  8 16:07:39 mys-MacBook-Air.local System Preferences[2795]: status= 0
```

Further googling these lines did not return any clues.

Comment: Same problem here with fresh install.

Comment: You might have better luck in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Perhaps superuser might be more appropriate?

Comment: Several questions about mysql in stack overflow base troubleshooting on a config file in /etc, which does not exist in the Mac version.

Answer (score -1):

You can try and disable pam authentication under your ssh server and see if that helps